# Is there a way to add multiple things into source of google_storage_bucket_object?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

The HTML files has a separate css stylesheet and svg images in it that are in different files.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "index" {
  name   = var.index_page
  source = var.htmlFile //add more stuff
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.website.name
}
```

Comment: You can perform a loop to add more file. But terraform is not really design to copy file and to deploy app, mainly for infrastructure part.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use Terraform [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset) funcion.
Put all your files in a directory and with a for_each iterate on the fileset.

```
resource "example_thing" "example" {
  for_each = fileset(path.module, "files/*")

  # other configuration using each.value
}
```

I hope is helpful :)